# How to populate the same layout inside a liner layout (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create a list. The list will contain similar objects. each object will have some images, text and buttons. I can put those items in a table layout and arrange them (child). But i need to have a list of these(childs) items. And i need to populate them by dynamically. So i just cant code them in an XML at the beginning.

How can i do it. Can you post some tutorials or samples.

Thank you

Comment: What is the data source you will be fetching the data from?

Comment: from a DB. Some other part of the system writes to it. I need to show it in a view. And i need the list to be scroll-able if there are lot of items.

Comment: And you already have the DB ready and just need to plug it into a ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me a lot in designing custom views as part of a listview -

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html

EDIT -

never tried may be where this is -

```
new String[] {"pen","price","contactid"},
new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text2}
```

replace text by imageviews in xml file

and then where this is

```
HashMap<String,String> tempnew = new HashMap<String,String>();
temp.put("pen",cur.getString(1).replace("+", " "));
```

repalce it with

```
HashMap<String,Image> tempnew = new HashMap<String,Image>();
temp.put("pen",Image1);
```

Image1 will be your image

Is this what you meant?

Comment: do you know why those XML files create a error?. DO you know how to make it happen?

Comment: do you know how to change the image using hashmaps?. I can add text dynamically but how to change image?